# Generator of a Feller semigroup on a coutable space

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let $E$ be a countable set in the discrete topology.

Let $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Feller semigroup on $E$, i.e. a strongly continuous semigroup of operators on $\mathcal{C}_0(E)$ (in the topology of uniform convergence) such that

- $f \geq 0 \Rightarrow T_t f \geq 0$ for all $t$
- $ \| T_t \| \leq 1$ for all $t$

Does it follow that the domain of the generator of $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is the whole space $\mathcal{C}_0(E)$?

Could you please give me the answer and at least some hint for proof or counterexample?

Comment: If $T$ is a $C_{0}$ semigroup of linear operators on a Banach space $X$ with $\|T(t)-I\|_{\mathcal{L}(X)}\rightarrow 0$ as $t\downarrow 0$, then $T$ has a bounded generator $A\in\mathcal{L}(X)$. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Thx T.A.E., I am aware of the result you re citing. But in this case I cannot be sure that $T_t$ coverges to $I$ in the operator norm, can I?